# Progressbar Js- this._container.appendChild is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, progress-bar

JS

```
$scope.activeGoals = [{
  "userGoalId": 1
},
{
  "userGoalId": 2
}];

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.activeGoals.length; i++) {
  var retirementBar = new ProgressBar.Line($scope.activeGoals[i].userGoalId, {  //getting error here
    strokeWidth: 4,
    svgStyle: {
      width: '100%',
      height: '5px'
    },
    step: (state, bar) => {
      bar.setText(Math.round(bar.value() * 100) + ' %');
    }
  });
  retirementBar.animate(0.43); // Number from 0.0 to 1.0
}
```

HTML

```
 <li class="item" ng-repeat="activeGoal in activeGoals">
  <div id="{{activeGoal.userGoalId}}"></div>
 </li>
```

While integrating Progressbar js in ionic app with ng-repeat, getting error like-

ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: this._container.appendChild is not a function

```
at Line.Shape (progressbar.js:2054)
at new Line (progressbar.js:1708)
at new <anonymous> (app.js:265)
at Object.instantiate (ionic.bundle.js:18015)
at $controller (ionic.bundle.js:23417)
at Object.self.appendViewElement (ionic.bundle.js:59908)
at Object.render (ionic.bundle.js:57901)
at Object.init (ionic.bundle.js:57821)
at Object.self.render (ionic.bundle.js:59767)
at Object.self.register (ionic.bundle.js:59725)
```

Any help is appreciated!